# Let $\mathbb{P} \sim \mathbb{Q} \sim \mathbb{R}$ be equivalent probability measures on some measurable space

Tags: bayes-theory, equivalent-measure, radon-nikodym

Let $\mathbb{P} \sim \mathbb{Q} \sim \mathbb{R}$ be equivalent probability measures on some measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, and let $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub- $\sigma$-algebra. Show that
$$
\left.\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d \mathbb{P}}\right|_{\mathcal{G}}=\left.\left.\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d \mathbb{Q}}\right|_{\mathcal{G}} \frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}}\right|_{\mathcal{G}}
$$

**My attempt:**

I am not sure if this is the way I am suppose to answer the question:

By definition, we can take the expectation of $\left.\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d \mathbb{P}}\right|_{\mathcal{G}}$ which gives:

$$E_{p}[\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d \mathbb{P}}\mid G_{t}]$$

$$=E_{p}\left[\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d Q} \cdot \frac{d Q}{d \mathbb{R}} \mid G_{t}\right]$$

Using Bayes theorem we get:

$$E_{p}\left[\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d Q} \cdot \frac{d Q}{d \mathbb{R}} \mid G_{t}\right] = E_{Q}\left[\frac{d R}{d Q} \mid G_{t}\right] \cdot E_{P}\left[\frac{d Q}{d \mathbb{P}} \mid G_{t}\right]$$

Hence we get the measure change: $$\left.\left.\frac{d \mathbb{R}}{d \mathbb{Q}}\right|_{\mathcal{G}} \frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}}\right|_{\mathcal{G}}$$

Comment: I think your solution and the other answer are wrong. The issue is that you have only proven that the expectations of the left and right hand sides are equal, but lots of non-equal measures will have equal expectations. In general, to show that measures mu and nu are equal you either have to show something like mu (A) = nu(A) for every measurable A (or some large collection of A), or you show that \int f dmu = \int f dnu for some class of functions f. You can modify your solution to pursue this second approach.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558790/radon-nikodym-theorem-for-positive-measures-chain-rule This appears to address the question.

Comment: @dm63 I think OP assumes the RN derivative chain rule as given (and already uses it in the first equality) and expands it to conditional distribution expectations (on a subalgebra) of RN derivatives.